# java8 stream op List<List<Long>>

Tags: list, dictionary, java-stream

i have a data set defined as `List<List<Long>> dataSet`, the element in dataSet(List) has 8 sub emelents, i want to use index 0 element group by the dataSet, finally build a map Map>, how to do this?
the old code is:

```
List<List<Long>> dataSet = .....; 
Map<Long, Set<Long>> a = new HashMap<>();
for (List<Long> data : dataSet) {
    Long userId = data.get(0);
    Long targetId = date.get(7);
    if (a.containsKey(userId)) {
        a.get(userId).add(targetId);
    } else {
        Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<>();
        ids.add(targetIds);
        a.put(userId, ids);
    }
}
```

Comment: your old code won't run at all. you are accessing userId and targetId variable outside their scope (the for loop). You might need to correct your old code. that will help us understand the requirement better.

Comment: sorry, that is my fault.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a specific implementation of `Collector`-interface that suits your needs.

> **NOTICE**: this collector also works in parallel, which is quite handy

```
public class MapCollector implements Collector<List<Long>, Map<Long, Set<Long>>, Map<Long, Set<Long>>>{

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<Long, Set<Long>>> supplier(){
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<Long, Set<Long>>, List<Long>> accumulator(){
        return ( m, l ) -> {
            Set<Long> longs = m.get(l.get(0));
            if( longs == null ){
                longs = new HashSet<>();
            }
            longs.add(l.get(7));
            m.put(l.get(0), longs);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<Long, Set<Long>>> combiner(){
        return ( m1, m2 ) -> {
            m2.forEach(( k, v ) -> {
                Set<Long> longs = m1.get(k);
                if( longs == null ){
                    longs = v;
                } else{
                    longs.addAll(v);
                }
                m1.put(k, longs);
            });
            return m1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<Long, Set<Long>>, Map<Long, Set<Long>>> finisher(){
        return UnaryOperator.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics(){
        return EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH, Characteristics.UNORDERED, Characteristics.CONCURRENT);
    }
}
```

you can use it in the following manner: `Map<Long, Set<Long>> map = dataSet.stream().collect(new MapCollector());`

Hope this is useful for you ;)

Comment: thank you for your help, i think the answer is useful for me!

Comment: @QinyiZhang glad to hear that :)